# Expression evaluator without PEMDASM

Tags: c++, expression

I have a question. I have these codes.

```
int x = 20 , y = 2 , z = 5 , a = 0, b = 2 ; 
a = x*y-z/b
cout<<"a is "<<a;
done;
```

when performing this, I want it to be performed like a = 20 * 2 - 5 /2 and  I want the result to be 17.5. c++ normally follows PEMDASM rules. How can I perform the expression without following the PEMDAS rule? thanks. I want it to perform according to the order in which they appear first, * appeared first, then - then / . thank you so much

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak wat. Just wat. What did you even

Comment: how will I apply it in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use parentheses:

```
a = (x*y - z)/b;
```

Comment: what I mean is that the first operator must be performed first. for example,

    x = y + z * b - a / c

addition must be solved first, then multiplication, subtraction then division. (which violates the pemdasm rule ofcourse )